# How to make the vertex $0$ frozen?

Tags: math-software, computer-algebra-systems, sagemath

I would like to define a quiver with the vertex $0$ frozen:

```
Q = ClusterQuiver(DiGraph([[0,1],[1,2],[2,3],[2,4]]),frozen=0)
```

But it seems that this doesn't work and the vertex $0$ is still mutable. How to make the vertex 0 frozen? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any documentation of exactly how to use this in [the documentation](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/combinat/sage/combinat/cluster_algebra_quiver/quiver.html#sage-combinat-cluster-algebra-quiver-quiver), but it does seem that it's the "number of frozen variables" so if you ask for zero frozen variables you get zero frozen variables?  In particular, I doubt it corresponds directly to the vertices in this way.  But I don't know much about cluster quivers!

Answer (score 0):

We can use the following codes.

Q = ClusterQuiver( matrix([[0,-1,0,0],[1,0,-1,-1],[0,1,0,0],[0,1,0,0],[-1,0,0,0]]) ); Q.show()